# Comparing actual and budgeted costs

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I am using Excel 2013.

I created an overview of the costs. Now I want to check the difference between the budgeted and the actual costs.

I use `=SUM(A1-B1)`, where `A1` and `B1` are both solutions of former SUMs (subtotals).

The solution given in the final cell always gives 0.

How can I change this formula to have computed the correct value?

Comment: That formula should work. What is the formatting of the cell your `SUM` formula is in?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simply subtraction of the cells just computed

```
 =A1-B1
```

---

In google spreadsheet for example the formula you used it works.
You can use even `=SUM(A1,B1)` or `=SUM(A1:B1)` if one of the two comes with its algebraic minus sign, else you will have the simple sum.

Maybe you want to read more on online documentation of office about the `SUM` command <sup>[[1](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUM-function-043e1c7d-7726-4e80-8f32-07b23e057f89)]</sup>.